# How do I keep forms maximised in MSAccess Applications

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2010

I have an app with about 40 screens that can all be called in various orders.

I have DoCmd.Maximize on the OnActivate function of every form but when you close a form that is in the foreground the form behind it is back to it's "designed" size.  When you then click on the form it activates it and makes it run the DoCmd.Maximize code.

How do I get the whole app to just run full screen?

Answer (score 0):

In Access 2010, you can use File->Options->Document Windows Options->Tabbed Documents, you can set the size of the form to the maximum allowed and remove auto sizing, or you can add code to the close button to maximize the next form.

```
Forms(Forms.Count - 2).SetFocus
DoCmd.Maximize
```

Forms.Count -1 is the current form and -2 is the form behind.